# Why am I unable to connect to the Google Cloud SQL from Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud

1. I have a Google Cloud SQL project : `cwdataproject` (Project ID). I have created a schema named `cwdb` in it. Its Instance ID is : `cwdataproject:cwinstance`
   I have provided access and privilege to cwdb for root user "root"
2. I have another app Google App Engine : `messageframework (Project ID)`
   `Project ID: messageframework`
3. I have provided Authorized App Engine Applications in  `cwdataproject` for `messageframework`
4. I have provided Authorized Networks for my local IP. and I am able to connect from local My SQL client successfully.
5. My code to connect Google Cloud SQL from messageframework app is as below.

Code:

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");

 url = "jdbc:google:mysql://cwdataproject:cwinstance/cwdb?user=ajoysinha;

 DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

**But is is giving the following error**

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How can we resolve this connectivity problem?
I am able to connect Cloud SQL from my local MySql client and do all the operation. but not from GAE.

Comment: Please go through all the steps which I provided in the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516319/google-appengine-cloud-sql-issue-with-spring-hibernate/14521643#14521643

Comment: Thanks Ankur, If my understanding is right I should change the Driver loading as below .. Class.forName("com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver") ..     Is my understanding is right

Comment: Yes.. And try to check if you have followed all the steps in my answer.

Comment: Again Thanks, will test today evening and let you know my findings .

Comment: Still I am not able to connect ..and i am getting same error ...         Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) Here is my code                                          DriverManager.registerDriver(new AppEngineDriver());                url = "jdbc:google:rdbms://cwdataproject:cwinstance/cwdb?user=ajoysinha";                                                       (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url);                          Can anybody give some clue ..

Comment: Where you are putting the password while connecting to Cloud SQL ?

Comment: Even if your root password is empty, you need to pass an empty string. Use this to connect **Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://cwdataproject:cwinstance/cwdb", "root", "");**

Comment: Thanks Ankur. It is working now

Comment: my pleasure to help you..!!!