# Issue with spring hibernate application running on GAE

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-sql

I have a java (Spring+maven+hibernate) application running on Google cloud with cloud SQL. Whenever there is a communication between database and the application it throws me this exception saying could not open connection communication failure. And in the last it gives me:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: Attempt to access a blocked recipient without permission. (mapped-IPv4)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.translateError(SocketApiHelper.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.translateError(SocketApiHelper.java:116)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.makeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:82)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.createSocket(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:497)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:362)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.AppEngineSocketImpl.connect(AppEngineSocketImpl.java:352)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:600)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:537)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:250)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 113 more

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:440)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:334)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.loadAdminLoginFromDetails(Unknown Source)
    at com.bullbeardevice.service.impl.CustomAuthenticationManager.authenticate(CustomAuthenticationManager.java:47)
```

My hibernate Config file :

```
 <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.abc.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">100</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>  -->
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">
                    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
                </prop>
                <!-- configuration pool via c3p0 -->
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">600</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">25</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">25</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.auto_close_session">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
  </beans>
```

My database.properties :

```
#db.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.driverClassName=com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver
#db.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.3:3306/abc
db.url=jdbc:google:rdbms://xxxx:xxxx/xxxx
#db.url=jdbc:Oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/XE
db.username=root
db.password=root
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false
#hibernate.cache.provider_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
#hibernate.cache.provider_class==org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
#db.sid=XE
# configuration for hibernate search
hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy=simple
#hibernate.search.analyzer=org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer
hibernate.search.worker.batch_size=100
hibernate.search.indexing_strategy = manual
hibernate.search.default.reader.strategy = shared
hibernate.search.default.worker.thread_pool.size=30
hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.ram_buffer_size=10
hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.merge_max_optimize_size=7
hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.merge_max_size=7
```

Comment: Please suggest I have been struggling with this issue since last 2 days.

Comment: You are connecting from `App Engine`, right?

Your connection string should look like this: `jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/db-name?user=root`, according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/). Also, by default you should use the `root` user with no password unless you manually changed the `root@localhost` password. Finally, make sure that your `App Engine` application is whitelisted in the Access Control section of the Cloud Console.

Comment: Hi juan, I have already changed the root password. and also authorized my app to access cloud sql instance. user user connection string also by its not working. Same error its giving.

Comment: Please help I have already wasted a lot of time on this.

Comment: how did you change the root password?

Note that the UI to change the root password in the Cloud Console is for the MySQL `root@%` user. Which is different from the `root@localhost` user that App Engine uses to connect.

Comment: I have changed it from the cloud console only. admin using same password to connect my application(using hibernate) to the instance.

Comment: I am able to connect from my Mysql client with the same username and password.

Comment: Try to follow all the steps as I mentioned in my answer to my own question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516319/google-appengine-cloud-sql-issue-with-spring-hibernate/14521643#14521643

Comment: I am able to do it from my local to cloud sql instance . but when I deploy my application on GAE cloud then communication fails with cloud sql.

Comment: @Ankur You can see my database properties its same as u have mentioned.

Comment: @Archit follow all 7 steps which I mentioned in my answer. Also enable Google Cloud SQL for your project, by right-clicking on the project and getting into Google App Engine settings.

Comment: Also have you white-listed your IP in Cloud SQL Admin console so the external apps can access your cloud sql instance.

Comment: I did all the seven steps but whta is can see here is if I use cloud sql from my local app engine, I can retrieve and insert data in cloud sql instance. But if I deploy my application on cloud and start retrieving or inserting data it gives me error as above.

Comment: And also I white listed my application in cloud sql.

Comment: I am accessing the cloud sql from the application deploy on cloud GAE not local. From local cloud sql instance is accessible.

Comment: Ankur I got the issue. The staging directory that is created on the local temp location there my properties file is not getting updated.

Comment: I also downloaded the code from the GAE database.properties file is not getting updated. Please suggest.

Comment: @Archit, as I mentioned. If you are connecting from App Engine, the username and password that is used is `root@localhost` by default _with no password_. You cannot change the password that App Engine uses to connect from the Cloud Console. So the fact that you can connect with that user and password from your local computer does not mean that App Engine can too.

Comment: @JuanEnriqueMuñozZolotoochin ... Issue solved I am able to connect to the root without password. Main problem was actually my database.properties was not getting updated. Now its working fine. Thanks Ankur and JuanEnriqueMuñozZolotoochin

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the application it will check authorization to access Cloud SQL (i.e your authorization to access your cloud sql).

When authorization happens for the first time, it will store OAUTH access tokens in your windows registry. So from the second time, it ll directly get the access token from registry.

If this token is changed or expired, you ll get the above error. So you need to delete the old token and authorize again.

Follow these steps to delete tokens from registry.

Open run and type **regedit** and click open.

it will open registry editor window.

Then expand,
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Javasoft -> Prefs -> com -> Google -> Cloud -> Sqlservice-> oAuth2

Right hand side you will be able to see Google oath  token.
Delete the tokens except default.

Now if you deploy your project it will ask you to authorize. It ll deploy.

Hope this helps you.